# cannot invoke initializer for type float with an argument of type (Any)

Tags: swift

I created my variable as follow

```
var unitTwo: Any
```

Then in my script I run a function which return a value of type Any.

This value can be an Int, String or a Float
ex: 0, 0.0 or "00:00:00"

```
unitTwo = returnTextFieldType(unitOneType: unitOneType, unitTwoType: unitTwoType).two
```

If it is a String before adding to my record function the string will be converted to a integer. (number of seconds)

Then later I need to check for a record but in my function it has to be a Float

```
let newRecord = self.checkIfBetterRecord(unitTwo: Float(unitTwo), unitOne: Float(unitOne), unitTwoType: unitTwoType, unitOneType: unitOneType)
```

But I get

> cannot invoke initializer for type float with an argument of type
>   (Any)

I have also tried to downcast with `unitTwo as! Float` but my app crash too and don't let me do this.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: `This value can be an Int, String or a Float ex: 0, 0.0 or "0"` why not use something like `NSNumber` for this?  That class is a wrapper for any numeric value and provides an int, float, or string accessor.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I just edited in my post, the string can also be of type "00:00:00"

Comment: That cannot work. Which float value do you expect with `"00:00:00"`? This isn't a valid floating point format. And a type `Any` is always the worst way. Use a more specific type or (create) a common protocol.

Comment: from "00:00:00" I get  a time in second like from 01:02:54 I get the number of hours/minutes/seconds and convert it to a Integer corresponding of the number of seconds. @vadian

Comment: (unitTwo as? Float) ?? 0.0f it will prevent your app from crash

Comment: @Pierre I can imagine what you are trying to accomplish, but there is no initializer which creates an `Int` or `Float` from a `hh:mm:ss` string. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: When I get the value from my returnTextFieldType, then I do a lot of others functions, I need to keep the string as it is at this point because I add the string to a database. But later before checking for a record I convert this string to an int. So when I call checkIfBetterRecord I have only Int or Float value that's it.. But it looks like because they are from a type Any I can't cast it to Float @vadian

Comment: It sounds like the underlying data type should be a float, an you should have methods that parse any other input type (string, int, et), to that datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment in Swift `Any` is always the **worst** way for declaring a common type.

This is a simple example for a protocol solution in *The Swift Way*.

The protocol `UnitTypeConvertible` got one computed property `unitTypeValue` and provides extensions for `Int`, `Float` and `String`.

The benefit is that a type `UnitTypeConvertible` can contain one of the three types and you get always the `Int` value by calling `unitTypeValue`.

```
protocol UnitTypeConvertible {
    var unitTypeValue : Int { get }
}

extension Float : UnitTypeConvertible {
    var unitTypeValue : Int { return Int(self) }
}

extension Int : UnitTypeConvertible {
    var unitTypeValue : Int { return self }
}

extension String : UnitTypeConvertible {
    var unitTypeValue : Int {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        guard let date = formatter.date(from:self) else { return 0 }

        let startDate = formatter.date(from:"00:00:00")!
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: startDate, to: date).second!
    }
}

let time : UnitTypeConvertible = "01:23:45"
time.unitTypeValue // 5025
```

Now you are able to declare

```
var unitTwo: UnitTypeConvertible
```

and write

```
let newRecord = self.checkIfBetterRecord(unitTwo: Float(unitTwo.unitTypeValue) ...
```

Comment: That's a very good explanation, thank you. I will try to understand that and get it work in my script and will let you know If I have any trouble. I will vote up after.

Comment: It works well, I saw you have change the string extension, is it better ? why using the DateFormatter() ? any issue the other method could occurs ? @vadian

Comment: Using `DateFormatter` and `Calendar` is smarter than extracting the components and doing the math *manually*.